# Align text in center of page

Tags: html, css, jinja2, semantic-ui

I am trying to align text in the center of the page, and it works when I do this:

```
<div class="ui divider"></div>
<div id="questions" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">

{% for question in questions %}

    <h3 class="ui left floated header"><u>{{ question.position }}.</u></h3>

<div class="question">


<div class="question_text" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;padding-bottom:1%;">

{{ question.question_text }}
</div>

<div class="question_stars" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
    <div class="ui star rating massive" data-max-rating="5">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui divider"></div>

{% endfor %}
</div>
```

[image: And it looks like this:]

When I try add a question number to it with:

```
<div class="ui divider"></div>
<div id="questions" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">

{% for question in questions %}
<div>
    <h3 class="ui left floated header"><u>{{ question.position }}.</u></h3>

<div class="question">


<div class="question_text" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;padding-bottom:1%;">

{{ question.question_text }}
</div>

<div class="question_stars" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
    <div class="ui star rating massive" data-max-rating="5">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui divider"></div>

{% endfor %}
</div>
```

[image: And this is what it looks like]

As you can see in the second picture the stars and the question is moved to the right slightly. The text will be different every depending on the question.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stars are pushed to the right because of the width of H3 tag (question position). Your H3 block and the div.question block are floating side by side.

To avoid that, try to remove H3 from the flow adding the following style to H3:

position: absolute